# Changing a string date to date datatype

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to sort a table using the column `Date`. It is sorted upside down i.e the date is in descending format.
However, the column `Date` is in text format: `'31-June-2008'`
How could I sort this column?

Tried this code to alter but didn't work

```
alter table bajaj1 modify column Date date;
```

Comment: why not order by date ASC or order by date  DESC

Comment: @scaisEdge When I use the order by it is ordered as strings, not the desired result

Comment: then the answer provided  by @nick should resolve your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your dates are not in a valid date format so they are being sorted as strings. So for example, `31-June-2008` is "before" `9-June-2008`. To sort them correctly you need to convert them to dates, which you can do using [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
STR_TO_DATE(Date, '%e-%M-%Y')
```

Note I've assumed when the day of the month is less than 10, it will look like e.g. `4-March-2001`. If it is like `04-March-2001` you should change `%e` to `%d`.

In a query you could use this as

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(Date, '%e-%M-%Y')
```

If you wanted to alter your table structure, it's probably simplest to add a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html):

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD sdate DATE AS (STR_TO_DATE(Date, '%e-%M-%Y'))
```

Then you can sort on `sdate` instead of `Date`.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3d6bca07db9e907408bda8c864c8ad41)

Comment: How would I use this in a query? Should I use it as it is or with a alter command?
It gives an error 1064 when executed